# I want to fetch JSON array data from php file to my html file in the select drop down

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

This is jsnExample.php file

```
<?php

$arr= array("India"=>array("Gujarat"=>array("Vadodara","Suarat","Rajkot"),
            "Maharashtra"=>array("Mumbai","Pune","Nasik")),
            "USA"=>array("Washington"=>array("Olympia","kent"),
            "New York"=>array("New York City","Buffalo")));

    echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

This is arrExample.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var obj,i;
    function myfun(flag)
    {
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)       
        {
            obj=new XMLHttpRequest();

        }
        else
        {
            obj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        }

        obj.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if(obj.readyState==4 && obj.status==200)
            {

                var data=JSON.parse(obj.responseText);

                getData(flag);
            }
        }

        obj.open("GET","try_json.php",true);
        obj.send();
    }

    function getData(flag)
    {

        var country_name=document.getElementById("country");
        var state_name=document.getElementById("state");
        var city_name=document.getElementById("city");


    }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
<select id="country" onchange="myfun(0)">
    <option>Select Country</option>
    <option>India</option>
    <option>USA</option>
    <option>UK</option>
</select>

<select id="state" onchange="myfun(1)"></select>
<select id="city"></select>

</body>
</html>
```

This both are the files. I just want to fetch all the array data of country, state and city to the drop-down menu in html file from array JSON file. I has stored country, state, city in JSON array. But I don't know how to fetch the data from array. HTML code is incomplete. I don't know the logic and code of it. may be u will think its silly question.

Comment: learn how to get the value of select within `onchange` handler. Can't hard code that value into `myFunc()`. Some javascript event handling tutorials would help you